# Is this use of callbacks idiomatic?

Tags: c++, callback, idioms

I noticed a common pattern in some of my code

```
std::string line;
if (!in || !std::getline(in, line)) {
  throw line_read_error(in,line_counter);
}
++line_counter;
std::istringstream sin{line};

// ...read from sin...

if (!sin.eof()) {
  sin.clear();
  throw incomplete_read_error(in,line_counter,sin.tellg());j
}
```

What I read from the line was different in each location, but the setup and post-read check were identical.

I factored it out, creating an object to hold my `in` stream and `line_counter`, and passing a callback
for the body:

```
class LineReader {
  std::istream& in;
  size_t line_counter;
public:
  template <typename Function>
  void with_next_line(Function callback) {
    std::string line;
    if (!in || !std::getline(in, line)) {
      throw line_read_error(in,line_counter);
    }
    ++line_counter;
    std::istringstream sin{line};

    callback(sin);

    if (!sin.eof()) {
      sin.clear();
      throw incomplete_read_error(in,line_counter,sin.tellg());j
    }
  }
  // ...
}
```

Changing my uses to

```
line_reader.with_next_line([/*...*/](auto& sin){
  // ...read from sin...
});
```

This is certainly less repetition, but it's still a bit awkward.

What I'm really concerned with, however, is whether it'll be easy for other
people to follow, as I'm really trying to make my code as legible as possible.

Would I be better off with something like

```
auto sin = line_reader.get_next_line();

// ...read from sin...

line_reader.check_done(std::move(sin));
```

Comment: `...read from sin...` made me chuckle. :)

Comment: This is matter of opinion but I like what you have done.

Answer (score 1):

The *normal* way to do setup + cleanup is to have an object whose constructor does the setup and destructor does the cleanup (RAII).

*However*, the cleanup you want to do, is to throw if you haven't read to the end - and throwing from a destructor is evil, bad, and wrong.  That means you can't use RAII in this particular case.

If it is really important to do the check, then the code you have will enforce it.  If it is just "a good idea", then I think the two calls (before and after) is probably slightly cleaner than the lambda.  (I wouldn't bother with the `std::move(sin)` - using a move doesn't really add anything here.)

Comment: Unless I missed it, the OP doesn't throw from the destructor. The throw is from `with_next_line`.

Comment: @RSahu - I think martin-bonner was just warning me away from attempting to implement this with RAII by moving that part of the code into a destructor.

Comment: @MartinBonner, yes, it does. Thanks for that.